# Ordenar coluna da tabela datatable através da query

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-datatables

estou tentando ordenar minha tabela pelo campo nome da minha tabela do banco de dados, mas o plugin jquery (datatable) insiste em ordenar pela id (primeiro campo da tabela)

Como forçar a ordenação através do resultado da query, no caso ordenar pelo nome ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Principais opções (assumindo para efeitos do exemplo que o `id` seja a primeira coluna da tabela e o `nome` seja a segunda):

## Durante a construção da tabela

Use o parâmetro de configuração `aaSorting`.

```
$('#exemplo').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]]
)};
```

Onde o primeiro valor(`1`) do array é o índice da coluna na tabela e o segundo valor (`asc`) indica se a coluna deve ser ordenada de forma ascendente ou descendente (`asc` ou `desc`). Múltiplas colunas podem ser usadas na ordenação incluindo vários arrays de duas posições na matrix (como em uma clausula `order by`).

## Após a construção

Você pode utilizar a função `fnSort`:

```
  var tabela = $('#exemplo').dataTable();
  // Ordena por nome e "desempata" com o id
  tabela.fnSort([[1,'asc'], [0,'asc']]);
```

## Ordenação padrão

O valor padrão [de referência](https://www.datatables.net/ref) do `aaSorting` é `[[0,'asc']]`. Para manter a ordenação conforme a ordem original do conjunto de dados faça:

```
 $('#exemplo').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": []
)};
```

---

**Fontes:**

- [DataTables - API](https://datatables.net/api)
- [DataTables table sorting example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: no caso teria alguma forma de eu deixar um valor nulo setado no datatable para que ele não ordene sem que o usuario clique na coluna ? assim ficaria ordenado conforme o resultado da query

Comment: Tenta `"aaSorting": []` (o valor default é `[[0,'asc']]`).

Comment: boa cara, o "aaSorting": [] deu certo e funcionou como eu queria, brigadao